# Replacing string in php

Tags: php, string, replace

That's my variable:

```
$name = "&6Mine &cHor&6se";
```

Now I want to delete & and letter next to &, so i need to replace it to this:

```
$name = "Mine Horse"
```

Is there a function which can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Must be done with regular expressions.

```
<?php
  $name = "&6Mine &cHor&6se";
  echo preg_replace('/(&[0-9a-f])/', '', $name);
?>
```

As this will only replace `&0` -> `&9` and `&a` -> `&f` to `""`

Also it will be possible to translate these color codes to html codes using the preg_replace_callback function using something like:

```
function toColor($hex){
  switch($hex){
    case '&0': return '#000000';
    case '&1': return '#111111'; // or some other color that represents &1.
    default:
      return '#eee'; // return default font color.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
$newName = preg_replace('/&./', '', $name);
```

This replaces `&` followed by any character with an empty string. See [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for details.

[Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/nX7xV7/1).